# Set a date with Excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to take a date and create a date in the previous month with a different day selected. I've tried using EOMONTH to go back to previous month and then to set the day to the 15th:

```
EOMONTH(TEXT(G9,-1),"dd")="15"
```

This gives me a `#NUM!` error though. Is there any other way to set a date to the previous month?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EOMONTH is in the analysis toolpak - have you loaded that?

Also your syntax didn't include an = sign - did you use one?  You want =EOMONTH, not just EOMONTH.

The correct syntax for the 15th of the prior month based off the cell G9 is

```
=EOMONTH(G9, -2)+15
```

Comment: Analysis ToolPak is only required for EOMONTH in Excel 2003 or earlier versions - in any later excel versions EOMONTH is a built-in function

Answer (score 3):

you could use

```
=DATE(YEAR(G9),MONTH(G9)-1,15)
```